# Your application server raised an error - It has been raised in your test code because Capybara.raise_server_errors == true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, will-paginate

Not sure what should I do about this:

```
Failure/Error: <%= will_paginate ads %>

 ActionView::Template::Error:
   Your application server raised an error - It has been raised in your test code because Capybara.raise_server_errors == true
```

using Capybara with Selenium driver for JS

Thanks for help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty self explanatory - It's telling you that your app raised an ActionView::Template::Error during a test - check your test.log and fix your view.